# Exception sending email using Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

I've been tring to make a webpage use **Gmail** as a **smtp Server** to send emails with Asp.net. Here is the link for the settings that google has set for such occasion.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Every time I try to send an email I get the "Exception caught in RetryIfBusy()" message..

Any ideas?...Here is my code below:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void SendMessage(string toEmail)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("myEmail@gmail.com", toEmail);
        msg.Subject = "Email Subject";
        msg.Body = "Here goes email body";
        msg.IsBodyHtml = false;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        System.Net.NetworkCredential netCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
        netCred.UserName = "myEmail@gmail.com";
        netCred.Password = "myPassword";
        smtp.Credentials = netCred;
        smtp.Port = 465;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        try
        {
            smtp.Send(msg);
            Console.WriteLine("Email Successfully sent!!");
        }
        catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException ex)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ex.InnerExceptions.Length; i++)
            {
                SmtpStatusCode status = ex.InnerExceptions[i].StatusCode;
                if (status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy ||
                    status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxUnavailable)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Delivery failed - retrying in 5 seconds.");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    smtp.Send(msg);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to deliver message to " +
                        ex.InnerExceptions[i].FailedRecipient);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in RetryIfBusy(): " +
                    ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: What do you mean the last one? What's `ex`? We don't care about the text that you placed there: `Exception caught in RetryIfBusy():`. What's the actual exception? What's the message and stacktrace?

Comment: `code`System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed. at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 read, Boolean readLine)

Comment: OK, now see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong port on Google's SMTP server. Should be:

```
smtp.Port = 587;
```

Comment: `code`System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.

Comment: Do you have 2-factor authentication enabled on the gmail account you're using? If you do, you'll have to disable it before you can use the email address.